# Tkinter Entry() don't get numbers from input

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a problem with Tkinter `Entry`. I'm running program in a loop creating and destroying two class instances. In the initial loop, everything works fine. After the game ends I'm destroying the Tkinter instance:

```
self.frame.destroy()
self.tk.destroy()
```

Then the program goes back to the main loop:

```
def main():
  root = Tk()
  data = get_data(root)
  root.mainloop()
  del root
  root = Tk()
  main_window = Main_field(root, data)
  root.mainloop()
  del data, root, main_window
  msg = "Play again?"
  res = messagebox.askyesno("Game Over", message=msg)
  if res:
    del res
    main()
  else:
    quit()
```

The main object of this loop to create new empty class instances that will work as the first one. The problem is after restart the Entry box don't load the input numbers. I have an empty string when I call the get() method:

```
class get_data():
  def __init__(self, tk):
     global mines_var
     mines_var = tkinter.StringVar()
     entry_box_mines = Entry(tk, textvariable=mines_var, width=50)
     entry_box_mines.pack()
     entry_box_mines.insert(0, 0)
     self.width = 0
     self.len_ = 0
     self.mines = 0
     self.tk = tk
     start_game_button = Button(tk, text="Start Game", command=lambda: [self.get_attributes()]).pack()

   def get_attributes(self):
     res = self.validate(len_var.get(), width_var.get(), mines_var.get())
     if res == "OK":
        self.tk.destroy()
     else:
        messagebox.showinfo(message=res)
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: It would help if you could reduce this code down to a [mcve]. For example, do we really need three entry widgets or could the problem be illustrated with just one.

Comment: Also please make sure you know how to use classes. Most of the time you shouldn't be using global variables inside classes.

Comment: @BryanOakley I added them all because i'm not sure which one is the problem here

Comment: Well, remove one and see if it changes the problem.

Comment: Nope still the same no metter which one i left

Comment: So, you've just proven you only need one Entry, so you can simplify the example.

Comment: what is the point of destroying the frame if You destroy its parent anyways?

Comment: also can't You just change frames instead of destroying windows? also just so You know, if You run recursively functions the function that launched itself won't finish until the function it launched finishes

Comment: You also seem to lack basics which means You should learn those first for example this: `start_game_button = Button(tk, text="Start Game", command=lambda: [self.get_attributes()]).pack()
` can and actually should (still just advice) be reduced to this: `Button(tk, text="Start Game", command=self.get_attributes).pack()
`

Comment: running `main()` inside `main()` is called `recursion` and sometimes it is not good idea - especially that you can do the same with normal loop `while True` (PL: wywoływanie `main()` wewnątrz `main()` nazywa się `rekurencją` i czasami nie jest to dobry pomysł - zwaszcza, że można to samo zrobić używając zwykłej pętli `while True`).

Comment: instead of `command=lambda: [self.get_attributes()]` you can do `command=self.get_attributes` without lambda and without `()`. And using `[]` to run functions in `lambda` also is not preffered.

Comment: inside clas you run `mines_var = tkinter.StringVar()` so you remove previous value. You should create it only once - outside classes - or you should keep value in normal global variable and later do `StringVar(value=global_value)` to set it back when you create again `StringVar`

Comment: and you shouldn't use `entry_box_mines.insert(0, 0)` because it will remove original value from `StringVar`

Comment: you may need also `StringVar(tk)` to assing `StringVar` to current `mainloop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is

```
mines_var = tkinter.StringVar()
```

which removes the previous `tkinter.StringVar()` from `mines_var` and it removes the previous value.

You should keep only the value in a global variable and later put it back in `StringVar()`.

You should also use the parent - `tk` - like in widgets.

```
mines_var = tkinter.StringVar(parent, value=global_value)
```

---

My version with other changes.

[PEP 8-- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import messagebox

# --- classes ---

class GetDataWindow():  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes, and `noun` as name (PL: rzeczownik)

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()

        # variables

        print('[DEBUG] __init__:', global_len, global_width, global_mines)

        self.len_var   = tk.StringVar(self.root, value=global_len)
        self.width_var = tk.StringVar(self.root, value=global_width)
        self.mines_var = tk.StringVar(self.root, value=global_mines)

        # widgets

        tk.Label(self.root, text='Settings').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='len:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.len_var).grid(row=1, column=1)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='width:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.width_var).grid(row=2, column=1)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='mines:').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.mines_var).grid(row=3, column=1)

        tk.Button(self.root, text="Start Game", command=self.get_attributes).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_attributes(self):
        global global_len
        global global_width
        global global_mines

        res = self.validate(self.len_var.get(), self.width_var.get(), self.mines_var.get())

        if res == "OK":
            global_len   = self.len_var.get()
            global_width = self.width_var.get()
            global_mines = self.mines_var.get()
            print('[DEBUG] get_attributes:', global_len, global_width, global_mines)
            self.root.destroy()
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(message=res)

    def validate(self, *values):
        return 'OK'

class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        tk.Label(self.root, text='Game').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='len:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(self.root, text=global_len).grid(row=1, column=1)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='width:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(self.root, text=global_width).grid(row=2, column=1)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='mines:').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(self.root, text=global_mines).grid(row=3, column=1)

        tk.Button(self.root, text="OK", command=self.root.destroy).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.root.mainloop()

# --- main ---

# default value at start
global_len   = '0'
global_width = '0'
global_mines = '0'

while True:
    GetDataWindow()
    MainFieldWindow()

    #win = GetDataWindow()
    #del win
    #win = MainWindow()
    #del win

    # create and hide main window before creating message
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    res = messagebox.askyesno("Game Over", message="Play again?")
    if not res:
       break

    root.destroy()
```

---

**BTW:**

Of course, it could be done without the keyword `global`, like:

```
len_  = 0
width = 0
mines = 0

while True:

    win = GetDataWindow(len_, width, mines)

    len_  = win.len_
    width = win.width
    mines = win.mines

    MainWindow(len_, width, mines)

    # ... the rest ...
```

Or simpler:

```
settings = {
    'len': 0,
    'width': 0,
    'mines': 0,
}

while True:

    GetDataWindow(settings)
    MainWindow(settings)

    # ... the rest ...
```

but I skipped this part.

I could also use `IntVar` instead of `StringVar`.